# Are there any compression and encryption libraries in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, compression

I want to compress some files (into the [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) format) and encrypt them if possible using C#. Is there some way to do this?

Can encryption be done as a part of the compression itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For compression, look at the [`System.IO.Compression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx) namespace and for encryption look at [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx).

Comment: NOTE: System.IO.Compression is great for compressing individual files.  It does not compress multiple source files into a single zip 'archive.'

Comment: I have been using ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory in System.IO.Compression (.Net 4.6) and it creates a single zip archive from the files in the specified directory.

Answer (score 7):

For Zip Compression, have you seen http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is already old, but I must add my two cents.

First, some definitions:

- **Zip**: Archive format for regrouping files and folders into a single file, and optionally encrypting data.
- **Deflate**: One of the compression algorithms used within a Zip file to compress the data. The most popular one.
- **GZip**: A single file compressed with deflate, with a small header and footer.

Now, System.IO.Compression does **not** do Zip archiving. It does **deflate** and **gzip** compression, thus will compress a single blob of data into another single blob of data.

So, if you're looking for an archive format that can group many files and folders, you need Zip libraries like:

- [Xceed Zip](http://xceed.com) (it does support strong encryption)
- [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)

If you only need to compress and encrypt a single blob of data, then look under [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx) and [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The [GZipStream](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/06/15/429542.aspx) class is a native way to handle compression.

As for encryption, there are [many](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SimpleEncryption.aspx) [ways](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/encryption_decryption.aspx) to do it, most of them in the System.Security namespace. They can be done chained (encrypt a compressed stream or compress an encrypted stream).

Comment: It's difficult to compress an encrypted stream, since you can't compress random data.

Comment: You certainly can compress random data, it'll just end up using nearly the same amount of space.

Answer (score 1):

[Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/) provides .NET libraries for compression and encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the steps can be combined, but .NET has good support for basic crypto. Here's an [article on it](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/02/10/dotnetcryto.html).

Answer (score 0):

If they cannot be combined, do compression first and then encryption. Compressing an already encrypted file will lead to poor compression ratios, because a lot of redundancy is removed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a useful topic:

[Help in creating Zip files from .Net and reading them from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000/help-in-creating-zip-files-from-net-and-reading-them-from-java)

System.IO.Packaging namespace gives you useful classes to compress data in zip format and [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms580548.aspx) rights management.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't anything you can use directly in C#, however you can use some libraries from J# to do it for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx

Should do just what you want?

With regards to the encryption, have a look at these links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/fileencryptdecrypt.aspx

http://www.obviex.com/samples/EncryptionWithSalt.aspx