# archiving folder in .NET

Tags: .net, compression, zip, archiving

I need to archive(zip/compress...) a folder in my application I use .NET4?

I try to find examples in google,but I didnt find nothing.

Any idea how can I implement archiving of a folder in .NET4?

Comment: do you mean compressing / moving?

Comment: Does "archive" mean "zip/compress" for you?

Comment: I've used SharpZipLib in the past.

See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359868/sharpziplib-adding-folders-directories-to-a-zip-archive

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905654/zip-folder-in-c-sharp

Comment: There are plenty of libraries for zipping in .NET. Just search zip, not archive.

Comment: No research effort, first google result -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DotNetZip library is [very well documented](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples) and easy to use.
You can download the library (just one file) [from here.](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

This example is all that you need to write

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "ProjectX");
    zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ; 
    zip.Save(zipFileToCreate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out SharpZipLib, you can get it on NuGet: https://nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/